# Python Function Called with Default Argument Different From No Argument

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, default-arguments

Let's say I have a function that takes two arguments, `x` and `y`.  If `y` is not given, then I'll create a default based on `x`.  Of course, I couldn't define the function with `def myfunc(x, y=x+1)`, because the default would be evaluated at the *definition* of the function, not when it's called.  Instead, therefore, I would define the function with `def myfunc(x, y=None)`, and in my function body check if `y` is `None` and if it is, redefine `y` to `x + 1`.  What if it was possible for `y` to be *anything*?  What if even `None` was a possible value?  Is there a way that I could tell a difference between `myfunc(4)` and `myfunc(4, None)` even though the default for `y` is `None`?

Comment: Your function can't possibly handle "anything" so set the default to something that will never be passed or that you know you will not handle.

Comment: @FredrikRosenqvist What if it were a new kind of sequence?

Comment: What do you mean by sequence? Give an example

Comment: @FredrikRosenqvist I mean *sequence* such as a list or a string or a tuple.

Comment: Yes a list, string or tuple is not None? I don't see a problem, you can check the type with "if type(y) is list"

Comment: @FredrikRosenqvist: There has been a misunderstanding.  I mean I am *creating* a new kind of sequence.  Any way, `isinstance(y, list)` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to know it's not set, this is the way:

```
NOT_SET = object()
def f(x, y=NOT_SET):
    if y is NOT_SET:
        # y is not set
```

This works because of this:

```
>>> a = object()
>>> b = object()
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: Could be even better using `if y is NOT_SET:`, this checks object identity instead of equality.